# Update a parameter based on input in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Okay so i'm playing with sqlalchemy and got a problem. here is the code

```
........
def Create(cur_date, trans_status):
    new_trans = 'Transaction(date=cur_date, status=[Status(%s = 0)])' %(trans_status)

    session.add(new_trans)
    session.commit()
Create('1/12/14', 'processed')
```

NOTE: class Status has processed, rejected and forwarded as keys/parameters
GOAL: create new transaction where Status key would be dependent on the input(trans_status)
EX: if user selects status as processed, the Status(processed = 1) should be created

Answer (score 1):

Well, `new_trans` will be a `string` instance and not a `Transaction` instance. How about:

```
new_trans = Transaction(date=cur_date, status=[Status(status = trans_status)])
```